# How to reindex or migrate elasticsearch 1.x to 5.x data

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-2.0

I have copy of old data i.e. Elasticsearch 1.x, I want to migrate or reindex in Elasticsearch 5.x.

**what are the methods and better way to do this ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Elasticsearch is able to use indices created in the previous major
>   version only. For instance, Elasticsearch 5.x can use indices created
>   in Elasticsearch 2.x, but not those created in Elasticsearch 1.x or
>   before.
>
> If you are running an Elasticsearch 2.x cluster which contains indices
>   that were created before 2.x, you will either need to delete those old
>   indices or to reindex them before upgrading to 5.x. See Reindex in
>   place.
>
> If you are running an Elasticsearch 1.x cluster, you have two options:
>
> First upgrade to Elasticsearch 2.4.x, reindex the old indices, then
>   upgrade to 5.x.

I would recommend to follow official guide from Elasticsearch by looking here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade.html#reindex-upgrade-remote, which should help you.

Comment: I write a sandbox in python to take data from 1.x and directly put in 5.x, so its automatically re indexed.... Thanks. above solution is also helpful..

Comment: @Dhairya Can you please help me out with the sandbox which you have written in python ?

Comment: I created that sandbox year ago... but I will definately try to find it on weekend... Just try to create python script that will read indices from ES1.X then write it into ES2.x, Then ES2.X to ES5.....